# Is there a way to get tree data as a list with the LightGBM Classifier

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, lightgbm, classifier4j

In random forest type models, there is usually an attribute like "estimators" which returns all the tree split as a list of lists.
I can't seem find something similar with lightgbm. The closest I can come is lgb.plot_tree which gives a nice visualization of a single tree. But I would like to use the data shown in the visualization in variables.

How can I get at this data?

Answer (score 1):

There's not something exactly the same in LightGBM. But you could use the [dump_model](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.dump_model) or [trees_to_dataframe](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.trees_to_dataframe) methods of the [booster_](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.booster_) attribute of the scikit-learn estimator, i.e.

```py
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier().fit(X, y)
clf.booster_.dump_model()
clf.booster_.trees_to_dataframe()
```